# Не восстанавливается Fragment в ViewPager

Tags: android-fragment, java, android

Имеется ViewPager c такой структурой ***ViewPager -> FragmentStatePageAdapter - > [Frag1, Frag2, Frag3]***
Код адаптера:

```
public class SwipeFragmentPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements TitleProvider
{
    private List<Fragment> views = null;
    private String[] titles = null;

    public SwipeFragmentPageAdapter(final FragmentManager fragmentManager, final List<Fragment> inViews, final String[] titles)
    {
        super(fragmentManager);
        views = inViews;
        this.titles = titles;
        if(views.size() != titles.length)
            throw new RuntimeException("conteiners has different length");
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return titles.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTitle(int position)
    {
        return titles[position];
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(final int i)
    {
        return views.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(final Object object)
    {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

ViewPager сам содержится во фрагменте:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public final View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup containe, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        final OpenSettings openSettings = new OpenSettings(getActivity());
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_with_viewpager, containe, false);
        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        List<Fragment> pageViews = new ArrayList<>();
        pageViews.add(new Frag1());
        pageViews.add(new Frag2());
        pageViews.add(new Frag3());

        SwipeFragmentPageAdapter swipeFragmentPageAdapter = new SwipeFragmentPageAdapter(getFragmentManager(), pageViews, getResources()
                .getStringArray(R.array.swipe_mane_page_titles));

        viewPager.setAdapter(swipeFragmentPageAdapter);
        viewPager.enableSwipe();
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(openSettings.getFirstTab());

        final TitlePageIndicator titlePageIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewPagerIndicator);
        titlePageIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

все три фрагмента [Frag1, Frag2, Frag3] содержат списки с элементами. Когда нажимаю на список, в Activiti происходит callback-вызов, выполняющий вот такой код:

```
private void setFragmentContent(final FragmentWithTracker fragmentContent)
{
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.activity_content, fragmentContent)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
```

Соответственно вставляется новый фрагмент. Так вот, когда я нажимаю на кнопку назад, то возвращается старый фрагмент с ViewPager, **НО** средний фрагмент исчезает, а на некоторое время  у ViewPager пропадает обработка  f**ling scroll**(жест возвращается, после нескольких попыток).    Если заменить **replace** на **add** при добавлении нового фрагмента, то все работает хорошо, но **add**  не подходит для моего случая.

Самое интересное, что независимо от того, какой фрагмент я ставлю на среднюю позицию, все равно пропадает именно фрагмент посередине.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В который раз убеждаюсь, стоит задать тут вопрос, и решение находится само  :)

Кому интересно, в MainFragment, при создании адаптера надо было посылать **getChildFragmentManager()** вместо  **getFragmentManager()**